# what is the difference between sampling from a dataset and a sample from a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, sampling, dataset

I see in different documentations that people show sampling from a dataset $D$ with $x \sim D$.

What does the notation ~ mean?

Then I also saw that for saying: for every sample in dataset $D$ we also use $\in$, ($x\in D$).

Can someone explain to me the difference between ~ and $\in$ and the usage of each one, please?

Comment: It may depend on the text, but I believe that usually $x \sim D$ means that $x$ has the distribution $D$, or that $x$ is a representative sample of the dataset $D$, while $x\in D$ only means that $x$ is contained within $D$ (does not have to be a representative sample or have the same distribution).

Comment: Word "sample" has very different meaning in statistic and in machine learning. In statistics, it means a (typically random) selection of _n_ data units (=observations, =cases, =points) from a population. In machine learning, "sample" means one data unit of some dataset. So, every time you read "sample" be attentive to the field/context it is used in.

Answer (score 1):

$x\sim D$ is not a typical notation if $D$ is a dataset. Normally the notation is used as $x\sim p(x)$ where $p(x)$ represents a probability distribution or the population. Abusing this notation, $x\sim D$ can mean $x$ is *sampled* from the dataset $D$, where every sample is iid, i.e. we get a random sample from the dataset. This dataset can be a usual dataset with finite size, or can represent an infinite collection; which is then referred as distribution. $x\in D$ is just a set notation and it means $x$ is an element in the set $D$, i.e. a data sample in the data set. Here, $D$ doesn't represent a distribution, but merely a set of values, which can be infinite as well (in theory).